# Magento Add Tracking Number Template Error

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a site that uses Magento right now.

I am having an error in the backend, when I go to Sales->Order->View(choose any order)->Ship.

When I click on the Add Tracking Number, there is no result.
When I checked on my firebug,there’s this error show:

```
this.template is undefined
http://www.myDomain.com/index.php/admin/sales_order_shipment/new/order_id/154/key/f58bdecb79687dd839f91cdc23bb1b9d/
Line 628
```

We could not move one because of ths error.

```
Magento Version: 1.4.1.1
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you go to 'invoice' and put a tick in the 'create shipment' box, followed by 'add tracking number'?

Comment: All add tracking number buttons are not working, same error. Even in the invoice

Comment: Click in firebug on this.template is undefined line, firebug will open file script where it happens. Can you copy that piece of code and paste here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to look at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/tracking.phtml:

Here you'll see the error being referred to by Firebug on the Element.insert( ...

```
var trackingControl = {};
trackingControl = {
    index : 0,
    add : function () {
        this.index++;
        var data = {index:this.index};
        Element.insert($('track_row_container'), {bottom: this.template.evaluate(data)});
        $('trackingC' + this.index).disabled = false;
        $('trackingT' + this.index).disabled = false;
        $('trackingN' + this.index).disabled = false;
        this.bindCurrierOnchange();
    },
```

More details on the prototype insert method can be found here:
http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/insert

You will want also want to ensure the following template object is being set at the bottom of this file as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
trackingControl.template = new Template('<tr>' + $('track_row_template').innerHTML.replace(/__index__/g, '#{index}') + '<\/tr>');
//]]>
</script>
```

This is where `this.template` is being defined.
See http://www.prototypejs.org/api/template

A few things to try:

1) Try a different browser just to be sure its not a browser specific error.

2) Try disabling any 3rd party modules via /etc/modules/company_modulename/config.xml

3) Copy a new version of the tracking.phtml from same or newer versions of Magento.

Comment: also worth making sure you haven't removed 'track_row_template' from your code (or changed the ID) as it will cause the Template Eval to fail. (Option 3 mentioned above will achieve this.)

Comment: One of my payment modules was causing the issue but just when the compilation was enabled, disabling the module ate app/etc/modules/ and reenabling the compilation solved the problem, thanks